# Why values in ArrayList always returns null as first value in Java?

Tags: java

When i use this code to generate a random 5 card hand in Java, i get the correct result, but every line of cards is preceded by null. Why is that? For example, i get nullJ♥10♥8♥Q♦9♠, i tried some checks to prevent it, but to no avail. Please, if you have any suggestions, tell me what have I done wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RandomHandGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        String[]  faces = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
        char[] suits = {'♣', '♦', '♥', '♠'};
        ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < faces.length; j++) {
                String temp = faces[j] + suits[i];
                deck.add(temp);
            }
        }
        int counter = 0;
        int generalCounter = 0;
        ArrayList<String> handsGenerated = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (generalCounter < n) {    
            String[] currentHand = new String[5];
            Random generator;
            generator = new Random(); 
            //Ako ne se pusne edin Thread.sleep dava tvurde ednakvi karti:
            Thread.sleep(30);
            while (counter < 5) {
                int j = generator.nextInt(52);
                String currentCard = deck.get(j);
                if(!Arrays.asList(currentHand).contains(currentCard))   {
                    currentHand[counter] = currentCard;
                    counter++;
                }  
            }
            String buildHand = null;
            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                if (currentHand[l] != null) {
                    buildHand += currentHand[l];     
                }                   
            }
            handsGenerated.add(buildHand);
            counter = 0;    
            generalCounter++;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < handsGenerated.size(); i++) {
            String displayHands = handsGenerated.get(i);
            System.out.println(displayHands);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
String buildHand = null;
```

to

```
String buildHand = "";
```

Answer (score 6):

This is your problem.

```
buildHand += currentHand[l];
```

You append all cards to the original value of `null`.

You can do this instead:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
   if (currentHand[l] != null) {
       temp.append( currentHand[l] );
   }
}

String hand = temp.toString();
```

Another note on the solution. It's better to use a StringBuilder when you are looping and concatenating. The reason being that the "+=" operator on a String creates a StringBuilder under the curtains. So in your current approach each loop is creating a new StringBuilder.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me a way to fix this?